# Excel formula to calculate elapsed minutes between 2 date timestamps only counting minutes during work hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with about 50,000 records where I need to find the number of minutes between two date timestamps but I need to exclude any minutes that occurred during the times we are not working.

Our schedule is M-F 8:30am-5:30pm, Saturdays 8:30am-1:30pm
We don't work Sundays or holidays.

As an example
Cell B2: [7/3/2020 2:16:21 PM]
Cell C2: [7/6/2020 9:20:23 AM]
The manually calculated answer for this one should be about 244 minutes. Task started Friday afternoon, Saturday was a holiday, don't work Sundays, task completed at 9:20am on Monday.

Usually, I come here and start writing a question and by the time I've understood my own problem well enough to post a question I have figured it out on my own but not this time! Help!

Update:
@ForwardEd shared this...

```
=((I2-H2)
-MAX(0,(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H2,I2,"0000011",$M$2:$M$12)-1+(WEEKDAY(I2,1)=7)))*TIME(15,0,0)
-MAX(0,(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H2,I2,"1111101",$M$2:$M$12)-(WEEKDAY(I2,1)=7)))*TIME(19,0,0)
-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H2,I2,"1111110",$M$2:$M$12)-(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H2,I2,"0000000")
-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H2,I2,"0000000",$M$2:$M$12)))*24*60
```

Where H:H is the Start Date Timestamp and I:I is the Response Date Timestamp and M2:M12 contains my holiday list.

It worked beautifully until I ran into an example like this:
H2 - 07/26/2020 7:48:45 PM
I2 - 07/27/2020 8:57:58 AM

The net result was -650.78333. It looks like anything that starts one one day and ends on the next is coming back as negative.

We want to measure the average response time in minutes for the applications that require manual underwriting. These start timestamps are times that loan applications were received online so they could come in any time of day. The stop times are timestamps that represent the system recorded response time. i.e. the timestamp where an underwriter first did something with the loan application. If a loan application was received at 7pm and was not auto-decisioned then a manual underwriter will need to do something with it the next day when we start working.

If that application came in at 7pm on Wed and is decisioned by an underwriter at 8:46am on Tuursday, we would want to document 16 minutes for that application - not 826 counting the hours between 7pm and 8:30am.

Comment: How are you supposed to know when it is a holiday?

Comment: There would be a list. There is a function in excel NETWORKDAYS(). If the start date, days between, or end date include holiday dates then those days would be excluded from the calculation.

Comment: How did you get 65 minutes?  If the task started friday afternoon at 2:16 pm and the work day ends at 530 pm, there is 3 hours and change time there.  That is way more than 65 minutes.  If I did the calculations right it should be 4 hours 4 minutes and 2 seconds barring rounding errors. OR 244 minutes

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA? The easiest way would be to make a table with working hours per day and then calculating the hours between start and end time using VBA...

Comment: @ForwardEd man... you're right. my bad. I edited in the problem. Good catch. Thank you.

Comment: @Nekvlek when i need vba code I usually record a macro then go grab the code from that and attach it to a button. I'm familiar but would need some guidance.

Comment: I think I can help you out

Comment: Let me come back to you in 30 mins OK?

Comment: your question updates change the initial question.  Off the top of my head I would look at pre-processing you data.  Step 1 convert all time outside of work hours to the start of the next legitimate time slot.  Step 2 compare the pre-processed time to the end time to get your response time.  If you can do Step 1 in a formula then you take that formula and substitue it into the formula for step 2 for the appropriate cell reference

Comment: @ForwardEd how does this information change the initial question? I want to calculate all working minutes that elapsed from start to end excluding the minutes that occurred outside of the working hours. Do you say this because I did not specify that a start time could exist outside of the scheduled workday?

Comment: @theteague yes... because the initial question was about start and stop times.  so you can only start during work hour and end during work hours is how it came across to me.  Its not that it cant be done, but its a requirement that was not taken into account and it is what is causing your negative number.  You are starting  on a Sunday which is outside of what I thought was valid start times.

Comment: @ForwardEd I asked this question on another forum where people have been much less helpful and on that forum I was able to upload a sample file. In that sample file I covered all scenarios and in at least two of the records in that sample file the start time began after hours. I couldn't do that here so I guess I should have mentioned it. I didn't realize it would change the dynamic of the solution that much.

Comment: like I said its a two part problem.  One to change the start time to a valid starting point to count from. The second is to do the count.  And depending on the answer to the first step you might even be able to combine it into a single formula...but I do not think it will get any cleaner

Comment: what is the longest number of days in a row that would be non work days?  I know where I am it would be 3.  Sunday, Christmas, Boxing Day all in a row.  Also how do your public holidays work when they land on Saturday.  Here, friday would be given to everyone as a day off.  In your example of not working the Saturday because it a holiday, are you sure the Friday is a working day as well?

Comment: 3 as well - Sunday, Christmas Eve, Christmas. We don’t work on Christmas eve. Actually if holiday falls on Saturday we may get the preceding Friday off.

Comment: Need to figure that out. So for me if  Christmas is Saturday and boxing day is Sunday, then Friday is a holiday, no one is working Saturday or Sunday, and Monday will be a holiday as well do to boxing day being on Sunday.  So 4 days in a row off.  Now there are only a few floating holidays, the rest are usually pinned to a Friday or a Saturday.  It  affects how you are going to shift to the next working time slot.  If Christmas is on a Saturday in my case, then I would have 24,25,26,27 in my holiday list. instead of just 25 and 26

Comment: I would post a question on how to convert time outside valid hours to start of next valid window or something to that effect and reference this question.  Look at the holidays you deal with in a year, and how they may affect Fri/Mon, and add in the part about regular work hours during the week.  I am currently working on something.  Got it to flag an invalid start time.  Now working on how I am going to shift it to the next window.

Comment: Will do this in the am. Thanks for your hard work. I was surprised this question didn’t net more than one upvote. It is more complicated to answer than it looks.

Comment: @ForwardEd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413206/how-do-i-advance-a-date-timestamp-forward-to-the-beginning-of-the-next-work-day

Answer (score 2):

What you want to look at is NETWORKDAYS.INTL.  Use this in conjunction with the custom settings to determine the number of Saturdays, Sundays and for the number of days in between your start and end time.  You know you have X amount of time per day that is non working time, and Y amount per Saturday.

Then you formula in essence becomes

```
(End time - start time) - X * No. Weekdays - Y * No. Saturdays - No. Sundays - No. Holidays
```

Now there will be some tricks in there in order to count your days. but that is the gist of what it boils down to in a formula.

The formulas that are doing the brunt of the work are:

**WORKDAY**

**NETWORKDAYS.INTL**

**TIME**

I avoided the use of an if statement by using a boolean operation that excel will resolve from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 when sent through a math operator.  Side note:  I read somewhere that this is also faster than an IF statement, but have no way of proving it and really does not matter on a small number of calculations.

#### WORKDAY

This formula will return the day of the week for a given date, and a set day of the week to be 1.  It will be need in this solution to determine if the end date is a Saturday which has a value of 7 in default setup up as well when option 1 is picked.  The format for the formula is:

```
WORKDAY(Excel Serial date, day 1 of the week)
```

For this solution

```
WEEKDAY(B3,1)
```

#### NETWORKDAYS.INTL

This formula will be used to count the number of specific days a start and an end date.  It can exclude a custom weekend or count a custom week.  If it is supplied with a list of dates that are holidays they can be excluded as well.  The basic format of the formula is:

```
NETWORKDAYS.INTL(Start Date, End Date, Custom week choice or workweek pattern, range of holiday dates)
```

When entering the formula it will give you a list of predefined options for the weekend choices.  It will not talk about the pattern.

The pattern is a string 7 digits long consisting of 1 or 0.  0's represents the days you want to count and 1's are days you want to ignore.  An important part of the pattern is that the first entry is MONDAY.  "1010111" would count only Tuesdays and Thursdays.

#### TIME

Excel stores date as an integer. 1 represents 1st of January 1900, 2 the 2nd of January 1900 and so on.  Time is stored as a decimal or if you prefer the percentage/fraction of a day or 24 hour period.  So rather than figuring out the math to determine what percentage of a day X number of hours is, it is simpler to let excel calculate it for us and make the number a little more understandable to someone who may be deciphering the formula later.  The basic format of the formula is:

```
TIME(Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
```

So as stated earlier, 6 key components need to be determined:

1. X - Amount of non working time after a weekday
2. Y - Amount of non working time after a Saturday
3. Number of weekdays
4. Number of Saturdays
5. Number of Sundays
6. Number of holidays

#### 1) Determine Weekday Non-Working Hours

Based on the supplied information that work day stops at 1730 and starts as 0830. There are a couple of ways of doing the math.  Subtract the working hours from 24 hours or count the non work hours at the end of the day and add them to the non work hours at the start of the day.

```
24 - (17.5 - 8.5) = 15

or

(24 - 17.5) + (8.5 - 0) = 15
```

For this example 15 will be hard coded into the final formula

#### 2) Determine Saturday Non-Working Hours

Similar to above.  Note that we are ignoring Sunday as it is a designated non working day which we already know is 24 hours or 1 day.  We are just interested in the time between end of shift Saturday and start of the next normal working Monday.  So it really gets calculated the same with just with difference end of shift time.

```
24 - (13.5 - 8.5) = 19

or

(24- 13.5) - (8.5 - 0) = 19
```

For this example 19 will be hard coded into the final formula

#### 3) Determine Number of Weekdays

Based on the description earlier of of NETWORKDAYS.INT and working with the assumption that holidays are stored in the range F2:F2, and using a pattern of "0000011" the number of weekdays the formula will be as follows:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000011",F2)
```

For this example the formula is place in cell **F6**

#### 4) Determine Number of Saturdays

Similar 3) adjust the pattern to only select Saturdays by using "1111101"

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"1111101",F2)
```

For this example the formula is place in cell **F7**

#### 5) Determine Number of Sundays

Similar 4) adjust the pattern to only select Saturdays by using "1111110"

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"1111110",F2)
```

For this example the formula is place in cell **F8**

#### 6) Determine Number of Holidays

To get the number of holidays there is not a direct way of doing it.  Instead take the difference between all days counted without holidays being factored in and all days counted with holidays counted in.

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000000")-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000000",$F$2:F2)
```

For this example the formula is place in cell **F9**

Now at this point I would love to say just substitute all of the above into the generic formula, but there are a couple of special cases that need to be taken care of.  You may have also noted I have not used the WEEKDAY formula yet.

So in order to count the number of days to which X is going to apply, its really the number of days minus 1.  The minus 1 is because you want to cont the intervals between days, not the number of days themselves.  This gets a little bit more trickier when the end day is a Saturday because there is still an interval there but Saturday is not counted as a weekday.  So the True count for number of weekday intervals is:

```
=MAX(0,(F6-1+(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))
```

I originally had the MAX(0, calc) in there to prevent the posibility of the day count being negative.  After arriving at this final format it may not be needed and you might get away with the following but its untested:

```
=F6-1+(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)
```

This same concept needs to be applied to your Saturday count.  If you job ends on Saturday you do not need to subtract the non working hours after the last Saturday.  You formula will look like:

```
=MAX(0,(F7-(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))
```

and again further testing is required to make sure MAX can be removed, but if it can then the formula would look like:

```
=F7-(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)
```

So now with the understanding how dates and times are stored, determine the time difference between start end end time and subtract all the non working hours.

```
=(B3-B2)-MAX(0,(F6-1+(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))*TIME(15,0,0)-MAX(0,(F7-(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))*TIME(19,0,0)-F8-F9
```

Now you will not want to use helper cells, so you can take each of the individual formula from F6 to F9 and wind up with:

```
=(B3-B2)-MAX(0,(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000011",F2)-1+(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))*TIME(15,0,0)-MAX(0,(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"1111101",F2)-(WEEKDAY(B3,1)=7)))*TIME(19,0,0)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"1111110",F2)-(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000000")-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B3,"0000000",$F$2:F2))
```

The formula looks unruly, but is easier to understand when broken down into its parts.

Now the last step is to get the answer to display in minutes.  There are two choices.

1. You can leave it as it is in an excel serial date format and change the formatting of to a custom format of `[m]`.  The [ ] will force it into minutes and prevent spill over to hours.  It will also round to the nearest minute.
2. You can convert the results to minutes by multiplying by 24*60 and the value will be in minutes and decimal of minutes.

[image: POC]

Note that:
A11 has Time formatting applied
A12 has General formatting applied
A14 has custom formatting of [m] applied

Comment: This is amazing. Sorry for delayed response, I've been out of the office. I'm going to play with this today. This clearly took a lot of time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This worked beautifully until I ran into an example like this: Start 07/26/2020 7:48:45 PM
 End 07/27/2020 8:57:58 AM. The net result was -650.78333. It looks like anything that starts one one day and ends on the next is coming back as negative.

Comment: deleted some comments and included them as part of the problem text

Comment: @theteague and dang it I closed that excel sheet this morning.  I thought I had tested a variety of combinations.  I will look into that one and see what tweaking needs to be done. May not be until monday though.  I have a bunch of stuff to do tonight and I am busy all day friday.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

Create a calendar table with the workinghours for each days in the year you have data in

Date     | StartTime           | End time
1/1/2020   1/1/2020 8:30:00 PM   1/1/2020 5:30:00 PM
...
7/3/2020   7/3/2020 8:30:00 PM   7/6/2020 5:30:00 PM
...
12/31/2020

Then paste this code in a module

```
Function CalcDays(dStart As Date, dEnd As Date, daysCalendar As Range)
Dim Cell As Range
Dim MinDaysCalendar As Date, MaxDaysCalendar As Date
Dim aWSF As WorksheetFunction
Set aWSF = Application.WorksheetFunction
'check the minimum en the maximum date in the calendar
With aWSF
    MinDaysCalendar = .Min(daysCalendar)
    MaxDaysCalendar = .Max(daysCalendar)
End With

'if the date you check is not in the calendar, exit the function
If dStart < MinDaysCalendar Or dStart > MaxDaysCalendar Then
    MsgBox "Date not in calendar"
    Exit Function
End If
If dEnd < MinDaysCalendar Or dEnd > MaxDaysCalendar Then
    MsgBox "date not in calendar"
    Exit Function
End If

'sum the time of all the dates between the start and the end
'pick min and max in order to start and stop at the right time per day
Dim tempTime As Integer
With daysCalendar
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(i, 2).Value >= CLng(dStart) And .Cells(i, 3).Value <= CLng(dEnd) Then
            daytime = aWSF.Max(.Cells(i, 2).Value, dStart) - aWSF.Min(.Cells(i, 3).Value, dEnd)
        End If
        tempTime = tempTime + daytime
    Next i
End With
'return the total time
CalcDays = tempTime
End Function
```

You can call the function by typing =calcdays in a cell and then give the startDay, endDay and calendar column as parameters.
There might still be some flaws in this code but I think we can manage those.

Comment: I created a table named WorkdayCalendar and it resides on its own tab named WorkdayCalendar. It has 3 columns, A:A = date, B:B=workday start time, C:C = workday end time. Sundays are excluded as well as holidays.

Comment: In cell J2 I entered =CalcDays(H2,I2,WorkdayCalendar)

Comment: Maybe with new info in the problem the van can be fine tuned?

Comment: I'll have a look

Comment: I've worked something out, see [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KEJQeEofBSSkLSs1XkHR7Gza666mq73y/view?usp=sharing) sheet. I tried to make some comments

Comment: Tried to open says I need to request access. Should be coming from barrettteague@gmail.com

Comment: I am able to open it in google now. I am going to play with this today. I can see how you have everything formatted and that may have made the difference. Thank you! I will let you know how it goes!