# How do I advance a date timestamp forward to the beginning of the next work day if the timestamp occurs outside of working hours?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of date timestamps and if any of the times happen outside of our working hours, I need to advance them forward to the start of the next workday.
Our work hours are M-F 8:30am-5:30pm, Saturday 8:30am-1:30pm, Sunday closed and we are also closed on holidays.
Examples:

1. Friday June 26, 2020 6:30pm should be advanced to Saturday June 27, 2020 8:30am
2. Friday July 3, 2020 6:30pm should be advanced to Monday July 6, 2020 8:30am. Because Saturday was a holiday and we are closed on Sunday.
3. Friday July 3, 2020 5:29pm should not be advanced because it began during work hours

```
    Column A |Column B | Column C | Column B | Column E
    Underwriter | LoanNumber | EntryTime_+3hrs | Desired Outcome | HOLIDAY
    TOM    | 1 | 07/31/2020 8:28:42 AM | 08/01/2020 8:30:00 AM | 01/01/2020
    DICK   | 2 | 07/30/2020 6:32:36 PM | 07/31/2020 8:30:00 AM | 01/20/2020
    JANE   | 3 | 07/30/2020 4:18:57 PM | 07/30/2020 4:18:57 PM | 02/17/2020
    BETH   | 4 | 07/30/2020 3:06:18 AM | 07/30/2020 8:30:00 AM | 05/25/2020
    SALLY  | 5 | 07/29/2020 6:35:37 PM | 07/30/2020 8:30:00 AM | 07/04/2020
    GEORGE | 6 | 07/03/2020 7:45:26 PM | 07/06/2020 8:30:00 AM | 09/07/2020
           |   |                       |                       | 10/12/2020
           |   |                       |                       | 11/11/2020
           |   |                       |                       | 11/26/2020
           |   |                       |                       | 12/24/2020
           |   |                       |                       | 12/25/2020
```

Comment: @BigBen i just figured out how to add a picture. Good idea. Thank you.

Comment: Text data that can be copied an pasted is better, but a picture is a hell of a lot better than nothing.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: That is awesomely better.  I am an enGineer (pronounce with hard G) not an arts major!  I reserve the right to make up my own words.

Comment: Tom's start time should be shifted to 07/31/20 8:30 AM Since July 31st is a Friday?  Next available time slot is 2 minutes later?

Answer (score 2):

Start date time stamps need to be validate and converted to next available time slot.

Current thinking is you have three potential outcomes:

- The date will need to be shifted next possible day starting at 0830
- The date will remain the same but the time will be shifted to 0830
- The date and time are valid and no adjustment is required.

so a generic formula might look something like this:

```
IF(OR(HOLIDAY,SUNDAY,AFTERHOURS),FIND NEXT WORKDAY,
IF(BEFORE WORKHOURS, SET TIME TO START TIME, ITS VALID TIME))
```

In order to check each condition individually for a potential day shift we can use the following formulas:

```
(ASSUME C2 is the start date being tested)

WEEKDAY AFTER 1730
=AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(17,30,0),OR(WEEKDAY(C2)={2,3,4,5,6}))

SATURDAY AFTER 1330
=AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(13,30,0),WEEKDAY(C2)=7)

HOLIDAY (list in E2:E12)
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,INT(C2))=1

SUNDAY
=WEEKDAY(C2)=1
```

The MOD function in the first two formulas is stripping the Integer/date value and just keeping the decimal/time portion

The { } is a manual list/array  is a nice way of doing multiple OR checks with out writing out each individual check.  Since these are sequential, you do have other options.

Now there is a way of flagging each case,  So now just rearrange and group together so you have three choices in a nested IF function:

```
=IF(OR(AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(17,30,0),OR(WEEKDAY(C2)={2,3,4,5,6})),AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(13,30,0),WEEKDAY(C2)=7), COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,INT(C2))=1, WEEKDAY(C2)=1), FIND NEXT DATE, IF(BEFORE WORK, SET TIME TO 0830, DO NOTHING))
```

Since each valid day starts at 0830 and invalid days have already been taken care of with the first IF, only the start time needs to be checked.

```
=MOD(C2,1)<TIME(08,30,00)
```

And the valid time is the only case left over so there is nothing to check for.

And you pseudo formula becomes something like:

```
=IF(OR(AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(17,30,0),OR(WEEKDAY(C2)={2,3,4,5,6})),AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(13,30,0),WEEKDAY(C2)=7), COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,INT(C2))=1, WEEKDAY(C2)=1), FIND NEXT DATE, IF(MOD(C2,1)<TIME(08,30,00), SET TIME TO 0830, DO NOTHING))
```

So now you just need to figure out how to add some days, change the time, and keep what you have for a value.

Adjusting the number of days to add had me looking at multiple nested IF equal to the number of days in a row that could be invalid.  Right now I have the worst case scenario being Thursday at 17:31 something starts.  Friday is a holiday as a result of a holiday on Saturday, Sunday is a holiday, and Monday is a holiday due to the Sunday holiday.  So first potential day would be 5 days away.  Ugly nested IF.  As an alternative I looked at AGGREGATE and adding 1 day at a time up to 5 and checking if its a valid date.  Then take the lowest/earliest date and setting start time to 0830.  To achieve this I tried the following formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(INT(C2)+{1,2,3,4,5})/((COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,(INT(C2)+{1,2,3,4,5}))<1)*(WEEKDAY(C2+{1,2,3,4,5})<>1)),1)+TIME(8,30,0)
```

Then next function you need to do is keep the date but set the time to 08:30

```
=INT(C2)+TIME(08,30,00)
```

and your do nothing is:

```
=C2
```

so now if we combine the crap out of that into one formula we wind up with:

```
=IF(OR(AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(17,30,0),OR(WEEKDAY(C2)={2,3,4,5,6})),AND(MOD(C2,1)>TIME(13,30,0),WEEKDAY(C2)=7), COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,INT(C2))=1, WEEKDAY(C2)=1), AGGREGATE(15,6,(INT(C2)+{1,2,3,4,5})/((COUNTIF($E$2:$E$12,(INT(C2)+{1,2,3,4,5}))<1)*(WEEKDAY(C2+{1,2,3,4,5})<>1)),1)+TIME(8,30,0), IF(MOD(C2,1)<TIME(08,30,00), INT(C2)+TIME(08,30,00), C2))
```

[image: POC]

I believe the desired date in D2 (red background) is wrong and should instead be `20/07/31 08:30`

#### reference to your previous question

Now in theory this could be substituted for every B2 reference in the first formula, but A) the thing would become even more damned unreadable and hard to maintain than it already is, and B) may cause multiple repetitive calculations.

Comment: Using a series of columns and formulas I've solved this. It was a nightmare. I'm happy to share if I could figure out how to send a direct message.

Comment: @theteague no direct messaging in this system.  Was I correct in my understanding that the time in red was wrong?

Comment: Yes, that was correct. And I did basically what you said. In one column I determined the necessary action - advance time to start of next workday, advance time to start of same workday, or take no action. From there I determined the number of Saturday’s and regular days between entry day+1 and response date -1 excluding Sundays and holidays. Then I determined the number of minutes to count for the entry date based on the modified start time. Then I determined the number of minutes to count on the response date. Lastly, I summed the first day minutes, between day minutes, and last day minutes.

Comment: It’s ugly but it’s right and I can maintain it going forward. I really appreciate the help. I hope to pay it forward soon.